# If cell contains matched value, multiply with another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I need to figure out some formula for this

I'd like to price some cookies based on the price for its ingredients. I have made a list of the price per gram/ml for every ingredients and I want to incorporate it to the list of the cookies' recipes. For example, for a recipe for chocolate cookies that'd need 200 grams of flour and that the price of a gram of flour is $0.14, that means the price of the flour of the recipe is $28.

It seems easy but I can't find a matching formula for this

I have gone up to finding the ingredient in the list, but how do I multiply the grams of the recipe (Column H) to the corresponding price/qty of the ingredient (Column B and E)?

[image]

Tried the IF function, but I can't find out how to multiply it to the correct ingredient of the list

I'm using Excel Home & Office 2019. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try: `=INDEX($E$3:$E$6,MATCH(G3,$B$3:$B$6,0))*H3` or you could use `VLOOKUP()` as well ==> `=VLOOKUP(G3,$B$3:$E$6,4,0)*H3`

Comment: you might need to change the separators from comma to semi-colon.